# how to split the time 

Tags: java, android, json

i need to split the time from datetime format using the json parsing .

Comment: Check my updated answer how you can use StringTokenizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] startDateAndTime = e.getString("startTime").split(" ");
String startDate = startDateAndTime[0];
String startTime = startDateAndTime[1];
```

try this to get your start date and time.

Comment: map.put("startTime", "" + e.getString("startTime")
       + "  @ olimpic Stadium"); .. am using the hashmap so its getting error when we add split to it

Comment: how to add split to this

Comment: you can add split, but it will return string array, that is why it is giving error.

Comment: e.getString("startTime").split(" ")[0] , try this for date , and e.getString("startTime").split(" ")[1] for time.

Comment: hi i got it.... thanks a lot.... i need only hh:mm from that format.. how i will get that

Answer (score 0):

In the current scnario, the date and time are seperated by a seperated by a space. You can split this string using space delimater.

Comment: Simply use:
String[] tokens = e.getString("startTime").split("\\s+");
String date = tokens[0];
String time = tokens[1];

Answer (score 0):

```
String response= " {"events":{"event":[{"title":"Audi urban future","startTime":"2011-09-16 00:30:00","endTime":"2011-09-22 00:35:00","description":"test","image":"http://audi.smart-media.no/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/20110919130749-medium.jpg","latitude":45.73154,"longitude":4.8592365}]}} ";

String startTime=response.substring(response.indexOf("startTime");
String finalTime=startTime.substring(startTime.indexOf(" "),startTime.indexOf(",")-1);
```